# Proc compare - why am I getting tiny differences when the values are exactly the same?

Tags: compare, sas

I am performing a basic proc compare:

```
PROC COMPARE BASE=dset1
           COMPARE=dset2 LISTALL;
  ID description;
RUN;
```

I am getting differences for some numeric variables when the values in the two datasets are exactly the same.

For example,

```
         dset1.variable1 = 1.0988718715
         dset2.variable1 = 1.0988718715
```

The proc compare has the following displayed for variable1:

```
Base       Compare    Diff.
1.0989     1.0989     -1.07E-13
```

I removed all formats and informats from the base and compare datasets and the length of variable1 is the same in both datasets.

Why is there a difference when the value is exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerical precission on the computer is not perfect, that is why proc compare can report tiny differences on "identical" numbers.

There are a couple of options you can use to ignore these small differences (taken from documentation):
METHOD=ABSOLUTE | EXACT | PERCENT | RELATIVE <(delta)>
specifies the method for judging the equality of numeric values. The constant  (delta) is a number between 0 and 1 that specifies a value to add to the denominator when calculating the equality measure. By default,  is 0.
Unless you use the CRITERION= option, the default method is EXACT. If you use the CRITERION= option, then the default method is RELATIVE( ), where  (phi) is a small number that depends on the numerical precision of the computer on which SAS is running and on the value of CRITERION=.

FUZZ=number
alters the values comparison results for numbers less than number. PROC COMPARE prints:

0 for any variable value that is less than number.

a blank for difference or percent difference if it is less than number

0 for any summary statistic that is less than number.

Default 0
Range:  0 - 1
Tip:    A report that contains many trivial differences is easier to read in this form.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146741.htm